# iPhone/iPad Application Development Limitations

Tags: iphone, ios4

Its quite annoying sometimes when you have no authentic sources to confirm if particular tasks can be done using iPhone Available (Public) APIs. Whats the preferred way of finding it out?.

1. Shall we go through iPhone documented APIs,
2. Ask senior developers ( which i dont prefer, you should not depend on others too much and theres no surety about their opinions ).
3. Mail Apple ( by the way they offer only 2 technical calls/yr :) ,

Any other ideas?
what do u people suggest?

Thanks Guys!

Comment: This site and the APIs are really all you need. Google around, ask on SO, and read the APIs. There's really no other way to do it.

Comment: Do you have any particular problem you need to tackle? That might be a better question IMHO. But what DexterW said is 100% correct. +1

Comment: And if all else fails, you could always email some Dev's I personally have had a couple of emails asking about how to do different things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The public APIs are documented on developer.apple.com in the iOS Reference Library.

However, the only absolutely authentic source on whether their use is acceptable is to submit an app and have it reviewed.  Apple just added a review board if you with to appeal a review ruling, so that may be the new last word (unless you get the executive staff's attention (e.g. SJ)).

If you wish more facts before submitting an app, there are a few sites which show which types of apps are being accepted and rejected, and if so, for what given reason.  However past acceptance of a type of app is not a precedent or guarantee for any future policy.

If you wish to try interpreting their rules and guidelines yourself, they are available as part of the Developer iOS Standard Agreement.

The Developer support people who answer technical question usually cannot answer review or approval questions, except to point you at the proper API documentation.  (The reason may be that these are often legal, corporate policy or marketing questions, not technical questions.)

Answer (score 0):

You can look at official review process from Apple here:
https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : Check the API.
Step 2 : If can't find an way in the API (may be you are looking at wrong API), use Google to find out whether it can be done or not.
Step 3 : If you can't be sure using Google, then ask SO.

IMO, Asking Apple is never an option.